# is there a way to find out what route and endpoint my service broker session is using?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity, dmv, service-broker

I have been trying in many way, from `sys.conversation_endpoints` to find out which route and which endpoint my service broker session is using.

```
SELECT conversation_handle, is_initiator, s.name as 'local service', 
far_service, sc.name 'contract', state_desc
FROM sys.conversation_endpoints ce
LEFT JOIN sys.services s
ON ce.service_id = s.service_id
LEFT JOIN sys.service_contracts sc
ON ce.service_contract_id = sc.service_contract_id;


-- Error messages in the queue
SELECT * 
FROM sys.transmission_queue;
```

Is there a way to find this out?

Comment: just to clarify, it does not need to be from `sys.conversation_endpoints`given a conversation_id or anything from this service broker instance, that would do

Comment: Message routing can be different for different messages in a conversation, and can change over time.